# When hitting Enter keyboard on a file path, open a new tab with the file content

Tags: vimscript

I'm new to vim language and I'd like to see a new tab opening when I hit the enter keyboard on a line containing only a path of a file.

When I create a map like this

```
nnoremap <buffer> <cr> :tabnew getline('.')<cr>
```

I get a new tab to open but with no content and with this title `2 getline('.')<cr>`.

I guess my problem is to somehow expand `getline('.')`.

Any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:tabnew` command takes a literal file name and not an expression. In order to pass it the contents of a variable or an expression, you need to assemble the command as a string and pass it to [`:execute`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#%3Aexecute).

This will work:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <cr> :execute 'tabnew '.getline('.')<cr>
```

You might want to also pass `nnoremap` a `<silent>` flag so that the Ex command line does not get printed when the mapping is executed:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> <cr> :execute 'tabnew '.getline('.')<cr>
```

For this particular situation, there's already a native Vim key binding that does almost the same as what this does. In fact, you could argue it's even better than this mapping, since it recognizes a file name under the cursor even if there are more contents in the line around the filename, and it also does lookup in `'path'` which is very useful to handle included or imported files (common in many programming languages.) The key binding is [`CTRL-W gf`](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#CTRL-W_gf), which is analogous to `gf`, but opens the file under the cursor in a new tab.

You could map `<cr>` in the current buffer to open the file under the cursor in a new tab with:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <cr> <C-w>gf
```

Comment: Doesnt one of the gf combos open a tab? C-w C-f maybe?

Comment: Good call @Ben! I just updated the answer to include `CTRL-W gf`, explain how it's different (better) than the original mapping, and how to keep mapping `<cr>` to execute that command. Thanks!